# latex3: Keep whitespace

Tags: expl3, latex3

Regularly, I much appreciate that within latex3/expl3 whitespace is ignored. However, there are situations in which I would prefer to temporarily disable this behavior.

One example of this is the definition of new messages, e.g.

```
\msg_new:nnn{module}{msg}{My example message}
```

When displaying this message, it will be shown with all words concatenated as the spaces separating them have been ignored.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\msg_new:nnn{module}{msg}{My example message}

\msg_warning:nn{module}{msg}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
    MWE
\end{document}
```

which will produce a warning "Myexamplemessage".

So the question is: How can I temporarily disable whitespace gobbling, so I don't have to escape all whitespaces individually?

Comment: `\catcode32=10` but you don't have to "escape" space you can use `~`  so  is only one character to type, so no more than typing a space

Comment: You will get the answer "use `~`". But your question is more interesting if you want to create a macro with the parameter separated by space, something like `\def\macro #1 {...}` or `\def\macro #1 #2 {...}` or `\def\macro #1; {...}` (semicolon space is separator) etc. You cannot use `~` in the expl3 environment in these cases.

Comment: @wipet Yes you can: `~` _is_ a space (catcode-10) inside `\ExplSyntaxOn`.

Comment: Yeah, using `~` works fine, but I would still consider it some form of escaping in the sense that I have to type in something else to produce a space.

Comment: the fact that byte 32 looks more like a space than byte 126 is an illusion:-)

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/942.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the treatment of whitespace with `` \char_set_catcode_space:n { `\  } ``. The reason this is not done 'automatically' here is that this relies on having no nesting, etc. (i.e. that the input has not already been tokenized): overall, the team have found that having consistency is preferable despite the slight increase in typing requirements.

---

To reset, assuming you are not using a group, use `` \char_set_catcode_ignore:n { `\  } ``.

Comment: Okay, so this allows me to restore the "keep-spaces" behavior. Is this effect local to the current scope? So if I were to define an environment inside which I'd execute this, would its effect be gone after exiting the environment again? EDIT: Just tested and the effect does indeed seem to be local-only

Comment: And for completeness sake: Say I would want to revert the effect of this within the same scope. What cat-code would I have to set the space back to?

Comment: @Raven 9 (`\char_set_catcode_ignore:n`)

Comment: Does the `l3token` module also define constants for the different default catcodes? E.g. something like `\c_char_catcode_ignore_int`?

Comment: @Raven Not at present: this is something we likely could think about, but  in many ways I'd rather move toward catcode-tables and avoid most programmers needing to set individual catcodes